# ASP.Net Core 6 Scaffold-DbContext login failure

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-3.1

While running Scaffold-DbContext command in Package Manager Console

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=111.111.111.111;Database=GC_db;User
Id=gg;Password=a@1234;Trusted_Connection=True;"
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Context
DatabaseContext -f
```

Throws an exception

> Cannot open database "abc_Form" requested by the
> login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'GC\abk'.

Comment: 1) `User ID=...;Password=...;` for SQL Login authentication; 2) `Trusted_Connection=True;` for Domain/Windows authentication. You can't use both at the same time.

Comment: Thanks....... It works fine for me after wasting a whole day........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**
You can't use both at the same time as above comments by "AlwaysLearning" reply

```
    Scaffold-DbContext "Server=111.111.111.111;Database=GC_db;User
    Id=gg;Password=a@1234;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Context DatabaseContext -f
```